# Tesseract finished training, but poor output

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I have 5 PDFS, which I converted to TIFF, merged with jtessbox, created a box file, and then went through the process of picking up each and every letter. After building the language, I tried running tesseract on the same big TIFF and converted PDFS, but I'm getting worse accuracy than just using the default dictionary. Is there anything I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Hi.. did you solve the problem? I am also facing same issue